# I want these two button in the same line but it appears in two line, how to fix it?

Tags: html, css

I want Button 1 and Button 2 to be appeared on the same line but it appears in different please help me to fix it. Thanks.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #copyit,
    #short {
      max-width: 100px;
      color: white;
      background-color: blue;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" value="click here" onClick="document.getElementById('copyit').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('short').style.display = 'block';"> <br><br>

  <span style="display:none" id="short" onClick="document.getElementById('shorten').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('copysit').style.display = 'block';">button 1</span><span id="copyit" style="display:none" onclick="myFunction(n)">button 2</span>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not provide any commentary on all the below answers, or accept the answer that worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
<style>
.btn{
margin: 5px 10px;
}
</style>
<div style="display:flex;">
<input class="btn" type="button" value="click here" onClick="document.getElementById('copyit').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('short').style.display = 'block';"> <br><br>

  <span  class="btn" style="display:none" id="short" onClick="document.getElementById('shorten').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('copysit').style.display = 'block';">button 1</span><span id="copyit" style="display:none"  onclick="myFunction(n)">button 2</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your `display:block` in the onclick event handler of your `input` with `display:inline`.

`inline` is the `display` default value for spans.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #copyit,
    #short {
      max-width: 100px;
      color: white;
      background-color: blue;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" value="click here" onClick="document.getElementById('copyit').style.display = 'inline';document.getElementById('short').style.display = 'inline';"> <br><br>

  <span style="display:none" id="short" onClick="document.getElementById('shorten').style.display = 'block';document.getElementById('copysit').style.display = 'block';">button 1</span><span id="copyit" style="display:none" onclick="myFunction(n)">button 2</span>


</body>

</html>
```

Not the answer, but try to use a `<button>` instead of `<input>`. `<input>` is for forms.  Use correct semantics whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was you were setting your span tags to `display:block` which makes them `block` elements. What you actually wanted to do was `display:inline-block`. But rather than that, just put the 2 `<span>` tags inside a container and show that, utilizing the `hidden` attribute (which hides the element automatically) and just removing it on click.

```js
function showButtons() {
  document.getElementById('buttons').removeAttribute('hidden')
  }
```

```css
 #copyit,
    #short {
      max-width: 100px;
      color: white;
      background-color: blue;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
  <input type="button" value="click here" onclick="showButtons()"> <br><br>

  <div id='buttons' hidden>
    <span id="short">button 1</span>
    <span id="copyit" onclick="myFunction(n)">button 2</span>
  </div>
```